# custom logic on elements addef by "if" binding with virtual elements

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm using the containerless control flow syntax for 'if' binding:

```
<!-- ko if: property -->
<div>
    <button type="button">My Button</button>
</div>
```

I am also using a UI library which for initialization requires calling in JS something like this:

```
$("body").initLib();
```

which will make the button work and feel in a certain way.

But since the `button` is a virtual element added based on the 'if' binding, the library won't add the functionality for the `button`.

What's the best way to handle this scenario?
Can I extend the 'if' binding for virtual elements?

Comment: You should initialize `$("body").initLib()` after your `viewModel.property` is initialized.

Comment: that's not going to solve my problem.

Comment: the button is added to HTML by KO at any time. I need a way to call initLib() after this happens.

Comment: Its can not be anytime, it will only be added when `property` field is true or have some value. So you can watch on it.

Comment: You're suggesting to call initLib() after viewModel.property is initialized. It won't work because if property is "false", the button is not added in the DOM by KO so the initLib() won't have any effect on the button at that moment. When property becomes "true", I would need to call the initLib() somehow again.

Comment: Wouldn't adding visible to div just work? ```<div data-bind="visible: property">```

Comment: @MikeFills What UI Library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a custom binding like

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.myLibInit = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
          $("body").initLib();
      }
  };
```

and have your virtual element like

```
  <!-- ko if: property -->
  <div>
      <button type="button" data-bind="myLibInit:{}">My Button</button>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: thanks. yes, that's one of the options I thought about too. but it's not pretty. I was wondering if there isn't other way.

Comment: by the time binding `if` executes, it will inject the button element in dom. so I think button wont be a virtual element anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the `initLib` code, the best way to do it is to use delegated events, which doesn't depend on the element existing on the page when registering the event handlers. The logic behind this is that the event bubbles up the DOM tree, so you register the handling in a container which is fixed in the page, for example `body`, and then specify the event to handle and a selector. So, if the user clicks the button, the event bubbles up to the `body` element, and, if it fulfils the filter, the event is handled. It doesn't matter if the element was there when you registered the handling. This is done by using `$.on()`, for example:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type=button]' , function() { /* handler */});
```

To implement the filter, which in this case selects all the buttons, you can use the `id`, or add `data-` attributes to the element (button), so that you can filter them.

jQuery docs [on `on()`, and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

If you cannot modify the library, instead of using the `if` binding, you can use the `visible` binding. In this way the handlers can be registered, and they won't be lost. *NOTE: I think you cannot use visible on a virtual element, but you can use an element with appropriate styling to make it look as if it isn't there*.

*NOTE: in general you should try to avoid mixing ko with jQuery, because they use different approaches and using them together can lead to conflicts*.

Comment: thanks. but one example of what the library is doing is, it enables the display of a nice tooltip (based on the "title" attribute) when you mouse hover over the button.

Comment: I offered two possible solutions. 1) Can't you modify the library, to use delegated events? This is the technique for "unobstrusive javascript", employed for example by bootstrap (by supplying the appropriate attributes). 2) If you cannot do 1, which I recommend, can't you simply initialize the library and keep the elements hidden, so that the eevnt handlers aren't lost? Do you have any doubts or problems with these techniques?